# Можно ли изменить цвет векторного изображения в xml android?

Tags: android, android-studio

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется вот такой код:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item
            android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

        <item

            android:gravity="center"
            android:width="36dp"
            android:height="36dp">
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="135"
                android:toDegrees="135"
                android:pivotX="50%"
                android:pivotY="50%"
                android:drawable="@drawable/ic_link_black_48dp" //это вектор
                >
            </rotate>

        </item>

  </layer-list>
```

Можно ли изменить цвет вектора ic_link_black_48dp из layer-list, не меняя цвет в самом векторе?

Код вектора выглядит так:

```
<vector android:height="48dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="48dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" 
    android:pathData="M3.9,12c0,-1.71 1.39,-3.1 3.1,-3.1h4L11,7L7,7c-2.76,0 -5,2.24 -5,5s2.24,5 5,5h4v-1.9L7,15.1c-1.71,0 -3.1,-1.39 -3.1,-3.1zM8,13h8v-2L8,11v2zM17,7h-4v1.9h4c1.71,0 3.1,1.39 3.1,3.1s-1.39,3.1 -3.1,3.1h-4L13,17h4c2.76,0 5,-2.24 5,-5s-2.24,-5 -5,-5z"/>
```

Comment: Не имею доступа к компьютеру, но тем не менее - пробовали менять параметр fillColor?

Comment: Да, пробовал.
fillColor влияет на цвет вектора, только если параметр прописан в самом файле вектора

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как изменить цвет из layer-list я не нашёл, но для меня подошёл другой метод.

В векторный файл я добавил android:colorTint, который ссылался на файл drawable с цветами для разных состояний кнопки.

Вот так теперь выглядит код векторного файла

```
  <vector android:height="48dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
      android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="48dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:tint="@drawable/color_state_toggle_rich_edit_text"
>
<path android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M3.9,12c0,-1.71 1.39,-3.1 3.1,-3.1h4L11,7L7,7c-2.76,0 -5,2.24 -5,5s2.24,5 5,5h4v-1.9L7,15.1c-1.71,0 -3.1,-1.39 -3.1,-3.1zM8,13h8v-2L8,11v2zM17,7h-4v1.9h4c1.71,0 3.1,1.39 3.1,3.1s-1.39,3.1 -3.1,3.1h-4L13,17h4c2.76,0 5,-2.24 5,-5s-2.24,-5 -5,-5z"/>
 </vector>
```

Вот так выглядит код файла с цветами (drawable/color_state_toggle_rich_edit_text.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:color="@android:color/black"
    />
<item
    android:state_checked="false"
    android:color="@color/color_toggle_button"/>
```

Решение нашёл на этом форуме

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847170/android-how-to-change-androidfillcolor-with-selector-in-one-vector-drawable-xm